# replacing single quotes in AWK in a column/field

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file that looks like:

```
'abc', '123'
'abc', '123'
'abc', '123'
'abc', '123'
'abc', '123'
'abc', '123'
```

I want to replace the single quotes only in column 2. I was trying the following AWK command, but its not working.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} { if(NF==2){gsub("\047", "")}; print $0}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give the requested *target* for which you want to apply the gsub function to.

Just change your code to this:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{{gsub("\047","",$2)}; print}' file.txt > output.txt
```

Here `gsub("\047", "",$2)` only operates on $2, second column.

Another thing, your condition, `if(NF==2)` wont work since NF is number of fields in the whole record, which is constant, in this case, i.e. 2.

Input:

```
$ cat file.txt
'abc', '123'
'abc', '123'
'abc', '123'
'abc', '123'
'abc', '123'
'abc', '123'
```

Output:

```
$ cat file.txt | awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{{gsub("\047","",$2)}; print}'
'abc',123
'abc',123
'abc',123
'abc',123
'abc',123
'abc',123
```

EDIT: OFS to `,`

Comment: I've given you an up-vote, but I'm not convinced about your 'Another thing' paragraph.  The condition isn't dreadfully relevant since the number of fields in the sample data is always 2, but it will work if the intention is only to replace the single quotes in the second field when the second field is also the last field.

Comment: NF never changes. It is constant. If a file has 4 fields in columns 3,4,5 and 6 fields in columns 1,2 => the values of NF for all columns are 6,6,4,4,4 respectively, for  columns from 1 to 6.

Comment: Please reconsider your statement.  Given a field separator of comma and a data file where line 1 contains `abc` and line 2 contains `def,ghi,123,498` and line 3 contains `111,222,333`, the value of NF for the first line is 1, for the second line is 4, and for the third line is 3.  NF does change from line to line.  Inputs are not necessarily uniform (and `awk` does not require them to be uniform).

Comment: That is correct, but by the time awk processes a record, the field number reaches its max value for that record. So it remains to 1 for first and 4 for second record in your example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Can I ask you for a `sed` example? `sed` should suite better here as it is an editor task. But currently learning it... thinking of something like a look behind regex

Comment: @hek2mgl I guess: `sed "s/^\([^,]*\), *'\([^']*\)'/\1,\2/"` should do the job, at least on the given data.  I've dropped the blank after the comma; it can easily be preserved if so desired.

Comment: @user2289280: OK; I give in.  We're talking at cross-purposes, and it isn't important enough to continue the debate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Works! :) After finishing the o'reilly I might understand :) (maybe you should provide this as an answer?)

Comment: @hek2mgl: the question asks for an `awk` solution, so this doesn't meet the direct criteria.  I'll leave it as a comment for anyone who wants to see it.  It's not a very complicated regex; it captures the first field `^\(...\)` which consists of a sequence of non-commas, then it's followed by a comma, an optional sequence of blanks, a single quote, another capture of a sequence of non-quotes, followed by the close quote; the whole lot is replaced by the first capture, a comma, and the second capture.

Comment: yeah, I see now. Thanks for the explanation. Having some experience with regexes in other languages, for whatever reason I never *really* digged into sed. will change this.. thank you again! :)

Comment: Why do you explicitly print each field `print $1,",",$2` this won't scale well. You should use `print $0` to print the whole record.

Comment: @sudo_O 'print $0' doesn't print the comma, in that case will have to specify  'OFS=","'. Otherwise its just a 'space'

Comment: @user2289280 my point exactly, setting `FS` in the begin block is not necessary, in fact it just gets in the way. You add an extra space in your output it should be `print $1",",$2` but as the fields are separated by a space just drop the `FS=,` and `print $0`.

Comment: This "solution" has several syntactic and semantic issues and doesn't produce the desired output. See @sudo_O's solution for the right way to do this.

Comment: I understand, thanks! Edited the answer. But I had kept it that way to keep it similar to what he tried.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively:

```
$ awk -v replace="'" '{gsub(replace,"",$2)}1' file
'abc', 123
'abc', 123
'abc', 123
'abc', 123
'abc', 123
'abc', 123
```

Answer (score 2):

`gsub()` will not return the string after replacing the `'`. It will return the number of replacements made instead. The result itself will be stored in `$2` after operation. Like this:

```
awk '{gsub("\047","",$2);print}' test.file
```

*Output:*

```
'abc', 123
'abc', 123
'abc', 123
'abc', 123
'abc', 123
'abc', 123
```

Comment: Using `printf` to output each field is not required, `gsub()` updates the record so it should just be a simple `print $0`.

Comment: @sudo_O Yeah, you are right. Didn't had this in mind. (have changed the post) Thank you!

Comment: @sudo_O Hehe :), just `print` will work too (of course)(have edited post again). Thanks again for the hint!

Comment: np, you may be interested in this http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/